# Excel Macro - Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I currently am attempting to create a simple data entry database system in a single workbook. There are 2 sheets, one named 'newEntry' and the other named 'Data'.

I have a command button, to which a macro is assigned. The code in Module1 under Modules is as follows:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim newEntry As Worksheet
Dim Data As Worksheet

Dim lastrowIndex As Double
Dim firstBlank As Double

Set newEntry = Worksheets("newEntry")
Set Data = Worksheets("Data")

lastrowIndex = Data.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

firstBlank = lastrowIndex + 1

newEntry.Range("C2:C8").Copy

Data.Range("A" & firstBlank).Value = firstBlank - "2"
Data.Range("B" & firstBlank).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, SkipBlanks:=False

newEntry.Range("C2:C8").Clear

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Upon testing out the codes, I keep getting the error above. I have looked at various other solutions and tried tweaking my code but none works. Please help to advise what is the problem here. The command  button is in [newEntry] and so are the cells with values to be copied.

> EDIT: The error pointer points to the following line   Data.Range("A"
>   & firstBlank).Value = firstBlank - "2"

Please advise what may be the problem!

Comment: should be `= firstBlank - 2` .  Also, you should dim as Long rather than Double

Comment: C2 is a cell that contains my column label (Customer). I want the code to look downwards and find the first empty cell in that column (thus pointing to that as the next cell) for me to place my values in there.

Comment: @chrisneilsen i've tried doing that. It returns the same error.

Comment: Why do you subtract a string literal (`"2"`) from `firstBlank`? What's the value of `firstBlank` when it blows up?

Comment: @user1777263 your code runs without error for me.  (as to the `"2"` vs `2` : why would you want to subtract a string? - actually vba does an implicit type conversion anyway)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Apologies, because my first 2 rows are for labeling purposes, firstBlank returns as 3 (if it's for the first entry) because the lastrowIndex will be 2. 

I have tried both using 2 or "2" but either case gives me the same error.

Comment: @chrisneilsen That's weird. My code is placed under the Workbook > Module sub-branch. Is that where it's placed in your case?

Comment: is the result of `MsgBox "A" & firstBlank` a `A1.0` before the error?

Comment: @Slai The result of    MsgBox "A" & firstBlank  returns a A1048577. I placed the code right before the error line. Weird! 
lastrowIndex is 1048566
firstBlank is 1048577

Comment: There is no row 1048577 - you have run off the bottom of the worksheet.  It's usually much safer to use something like `lastrowIndex = Data.Cells(Rows.Count,"C").End(xlUp).Row` when trying to get the last occupied cell in a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a check to see if you hit the last row in the column should column C have only empty cells beneath row 2

```
lastrowIndex = Data.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row
If lastrowIndex = Data.Rows.Count Then lastrowIndex = 2 '<--| if you hit the last row in the column then set lastrowIndex to "header" row index
firstBlank = lastrowIndex + 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The code worked like magic! Not really sure why my original code went off the charts and showed such a weird row number. Many thanks once again!

Comment: you are welcome. your code _went off the chart_ as a consequence of having empty cells beneath C2 only, so that `.End(xlDown).Row' hits the bottom cell in the column returning its row index and `lastrowIndex + 1` exceeds it. `Data.Range("C2").End(xlDown)` behaviour is the same as if you select C2 and then pres CTRL+ArrowDown
`